# WPF C# UIControl wobble like iPhone Menu Icon

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

What should I use to make my WPF UIControl (e.g. Canvas, Buttons etc.) to wobble like the iPhone menu icon (after hold-press). I'm trying to create a same effect on my Desktop application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/ShakingaButtonwithDoubleAnimation.htm) should push you in the right direction.

```
<StackPanel xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12" />
            <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5 0.5" />
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <RotateTransform />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle">
                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                From="-5" To="5" Duration="0:0:0.05" 
                                AutoReverse="True"
                                RepeatBehavior="3x"
                                FillBehavior="Stop" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <Button>Click me to shake</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I've come up with:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Window.Resources>        
        <PathGeometry x:Key="pathUpperHalf" Figures="M 100,100 A 1,1 0 1 1 101,100 " />
        <PathGeometry x:Key="pathLowerHalf" Figures="M 101,100 A 1,1 0 1 1 100,100" />

        <Storyboard x:Key="iconCircularMovement" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetName="icon"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                PathGeometry="{StaticResource pathUpperHalf}"
                Duration="0:0:0.1" BeginTime="0:0:0" RepeatBehavior="1x" AutoReverse="False" Source="X" />
            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetName="icon"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                PathGeometry="{StaticResource pathUpperHalf}"
                Duration="0:0:0.1" BeginTime="0:0:0" RepeatBehavior="1x" AutoReverse="False" Source="Y" />

            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetName="icon"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                PathGeometry="{StaticResource pathLowerHalf}"
                Duration="0:0:0.1" BeginTime="0:0:0.1" RepeatBehavior="1x" AutoReverse="False" Source="X" />
            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetName="icon"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                PathGeometry="{StaticResource pathLowerHalf}"
                Duration="0:0:0.1" BeginTime="0:0:0.1" RepeatBehavior="1x" AutoReverse="False" Source="Y" />
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Key="iconRotate" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotationTransformation"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                From="-5" To="5" Duration="0:0:0.09" BeginTime="0:0:0" AutoReverse="True" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <Canvas>            
            <Rectangle x:Name="icon" Width="60" Height="60" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="RotationTransformation" Angle="0" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind is just:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var circ = FindResource("iconCircularMovement") as Storyboard;
            var rot = FindResource("iconRotate") as Storyboard;
            if (circ != null) circ.Begin();
            if (rot != null) rot.Begin();
        }
```